# How to exchange binary data between c++ and java using protocol buffers and ZeroMQ

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers, zeromq, binary-data

<sup>*Α protocol buffers beginner here.*</sup>

I have a C++ application that has access to binary data via a method call that returns **`char *`**.
I would like to put these pieces of data to a `buffer`,
serialize them using protocol buffers,
send them over the network using `ZeroMQ` and receive and parse them from a Java application.

This is what I came up so far:

## c++ side

```
// Pointer to the binary data
char *buffer = buf->Buffer();

// Serialize data using protocol buffers
messaging::RequestMessage* msg = new messaging::RequestMessage;
msg->set_description("data");
msg->set_value(buffer);

int size = msg->ByteSize();
char *serialBuffer = malloc(size);
msg->SerializeToArray(serialBuffer, size);

// Send data using ZeroMQ
mq.connect(ss.str());
mq.send((char *)serialBuffer, size);
```

## .proto file

```
package messaging;

message RequestMessage {
    required string description = 1;
    optional bytes value = 2;
}
```

## java side

```
// Receive data to byte[] array
byte[] request;

// Deserialize data
Request.RequestMessage msg = Request.RequestMessage.parseFrom(request);
byte[] test = msg.getValue().toByteArray();

System.out.println("Size of bytestring value " + msg.getValue().size());

process(msg.getDescription(), msg.getValue().toByteArray());
```

Is this correct?
Although the binary data size is 37062 bytes,
`msg->ByteSize()` only reports 4 bytes, so I guess that protocol buffers treat `char*` as a `string` array and stop as soon as an `\0` is found.
What should I use instead?

Comment: I suggest you try it.

Comment: this is not the original code, and it cant compile as it since `buffer` is declared twice ...

Comment: Corrected the buffer typo

Comment: There is a set_value which takes a second size param, does it work? I think the current behaviour is logical since there is no way for protobuf to know how large your array is without you telling it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg->set_value(buffer);
```

Here, you aren't giving protobuf any way to know how big `buffer` is. You are only passing it a pointer to the beginning of the buffer. Therefore protobuf assumes you're using the C convention of passing a string which ends at the first NUL byte.

In order to tell protobuf how big the buffer is, you must also pass as size:

```
msg->set_value(buffer, buf->Size());
```

(I'm only guessing that `buf` has a `Size()` method; you'll have to check the documentation for whatever type this is.)